# Error building Tensorflow on CentOS 7

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, swig

I am trying to compile Tensorflow (r1.3) on CentOS 7.

> My environment: gcc (g++) 7.20, bazel 0.5.3, python3 (with all
>   necessary dependencies listed on tensorflow web site), swig 3.0.12,
>   openjdk 8. Everything is installed in the users scope, without root access.

Whenever I am trying to build a python package invoking following command

"`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`"

I am getting this error:

> .....
>
> 2017-08-24 11:40:35.734659: W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_gen_lib.cc:372] Squeeze can't find input
>   squeeze_dims to rename ERROR:
>   /home/data/software/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:2762:1:
>   Couldn't build file tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.cc:
>   SWIGing tensorflow/python/tensorflow.i failed (Exit 1).
>
> ...

However building C++ lib (bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so) working without any issues

Am I doing something wrong?

Update 25.08.2017:
ok, it seems that SWIG is build automatically from source when running bazel build. The version of shipped SWIG version is 3.0.8. But still, I have no clue how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved by using bazel version 0.5.1. Newer version producing the same error.